# Dropbox API using Python (flask) : authentication

Tags: python, authentication, flask, dropbox

I have to develop a service (using flask and dropbox API) in order to synchronize a server with my dropbox account. (This service has to be run in back in background as a daemon)

First, I have begun with "authentication" : in the beginning I used OAuth 2 (but it was an issue that every time, the client has to confirm the authorization)

So, now I am using an authentication with a generated access token :

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('ACCESS TOKEN')
```

So I have some questions:

1) Is it recommended and secure to use such authentication ?! otherwise , what it the best solution for this ?

2) What is the advantage of using the microframework flask in that case , because until now I'm just using native Python language

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, using an OAuth 2 access token is the right way to authorize API calls to the Dropbox API.

Note that you don't have to process the authorization flow each time though. You can store and re-use the access token once you retrieve it once.

Comment: So , using generated access token ( just to connect to my own account without going through the authorization flow.)is not recommended ?! why ?!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. You can certainly use a generated token like that.